# Listing subcategories in osclass

Tags: php, html, function, osclass

How can I list subcategories for a particular main category in osclass?

Eg I need all subcategories belonging  to category id 2. How can I do it? Can I get a code for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution

```
<?php
    View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('category', osc_get_category('id', 1));
    osc_goto_first_category();
?>

<span><?php echo osc_category_name(); ?></span><br/>

<?php while(osc_has_subcategories()): ?>
    <span class=""><?php echo osc_category_name(); ?></span><br/>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: How do I add a limit in this for subcategories